# Joomla custom form action doesn't work

Tags: php, forms, joomla

I'm learning how to make my own module on Joomla.

MyModule **mod_planejamentomensal.php** is like this:

```
//No direct access 
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/helper.php';

Jhtml::_('jquery.framework');
Jhtml::_('jquery.ui');
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidator');
JHtml::script(JURI::base() . '/modules/mod_planejamentomensal/js/jquery-3.3.1.js');
JHtml::script(JURI::base() . '/modules/mod_planejamentomensal/js/jquery.mask.js');
```

**default.php** has my form (with some other fields and jQuery, I'm copying part of it here so it won't be too long):

```
  <div class="planj-mensal-form">
  <form method="post" name="frmCasdastra" class="form-validate" action="<?php JURI::base() . '/modules/mod_planejamentomensal/tmpl/adicionaForm.php' ?>">
    <div class="divTable">
        <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableColumn">
                <b>Solicitação nº:</b> <?php //echo $solicitacaoTemp; ?>
            </div>
        </div>


      <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divTableColumn divTableColumn1">
                <b>Agência:</b> <?php echo $grupo; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="divTableColumn divTableColumn2">
                <div class="divLabel"><label for="mes">Mês Referência:</label></div>
                <div class="divInput">
                <select name="mes">
                <?php 
                    $select = $planMensal->setSelect($mes, 'mes', date('m',strtotime('+1 month'))); 
                    echo $select;
                ?>
                </select>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
            <div class="divTableRow">
            <div class="divtableColumnBotao">
                <div class="divInput">
                    <input name="add" type="button" value="Adicionar mais um formulário" id="add">
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>  
</div>
```

So, my form  action above points to **adicionaForm.php** which is like:

```
 <?php

 defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$input = new JInput;
$teste = $input->get('mes',null);

echo "Show: "+$teste;
?>
```

But when I click on submit button nothing happens...I Know there must be something on Joomla that I'm doing wrong. I tried to read documentation for forms but I didn't understand much of it. Can anyone please give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, at first I thought my action address was somehow wrong. But I got the answer from another site and figure this out: my code wasn't working because of the button's input type.

So I changed it from:

```
<input name="add" type="button" value="Adicionar mais um formulário" id="add">
```

To:

```
<input name="add" type="submit" value="Adicionar mais um formulário" id="add">
```

And it worked just fine.